# Rename "boxfuse" tag to "cloudcaptain"

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

We run the company behind Boxfuse and recently rebranded the Boxfuse product as CloudCaptain. Could someone please rename the [boxfuse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/boxfuse) tag to [cloudcaptain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cloudcaptain) to reflect this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The tag has been renamed and a synonym created. I've also updated the tag wiki so it starts with "CloudCaptain (previously BoxFuse)" instead of "Boxfuse (now CloudCaptain)"

Comment: Thanks! Truly appreciated! 